# Laravel migration's rollback transactions on any fails

Tags: php, laravel

So, idea is rollback any changes if migrations fails, even we have 30 migrations, but one migration fail it should migrate nothing.

I am trying:

```
    \DB::connection($this->getConnectionName($databaseName))->beginTransaction();
    $migrator = app(Migrator::class);
    $migrator->setConnection($this->getConnectionName($databaseName));

    try {
        $migrator->run('database/workspace/migrations', [
            '--force' => env('APP_ENV') === 'production',
        ]);

        \DB::connection($this->getConnectionName($databaseName))->commit();
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        \DB::connection($this->getConnectionName($databaseName))->rollBack();
        throw $exception;
    }
```

But in this case in says there are no any active transactions.

How can I do migration commands as transactions?

---

I also tried

```
$migrator = app(Migrator::class);
        $migrator->setConnection($this->getConnectionName($databaseName));

        try {
            $migrationsPath = 'database/workspace/migrations';
            $files = $migrator->getMigrationFiles($migrationsPath);

            $migrations = $migrator->pendingMigrations($files, $migrator->getRepository()->getRan());

            $batch = $migrator->getRepository()->getNextBatchNumber();

            foreach ($migrations as $migration) {
                $migrator->runUp($migration, $batch, 0);
            }

            \DB::connection($this->getConnectionName($databaseName))->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            \DB::connection($this->getConnectionName($databaseName))->rollBack();
            throw $exception;
        }
```

Migrations are still not commited and rollbacked.

Comment: Beware that any DDL statements (such as adding a column to a table) cannot be rollbacked.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code :
So, to fall on your case I created a new command file:

```
php artisan make:command RollbackAllMigrationsAndDataOnFail
```

Class:

```
class RollbackAllMigrationsAndDataOnFail extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'migrate:rollbackwhenfails';
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    public function handle()
    {
        $databaseName = 'mysql'; // Replace this with Database Connections from config/database.php

        $connection = DB::connection($this->getConnectionName($databaseName));

        try {
            $connection->beginTransaction();
            $migrationsPath = 'database/workspace/migrations';

            $restorationClosure = function () use ($connection) {
                $connection->rollBack();
                $this->info('Rollback failed. Data has been restored.');
                exit(1);
            };

            $this->call('migrate:rollback', [
                '--path' => $migrationsPath,
                '--force' => true,
                '--pretend' => true,
            ]);

            $this->call('migrate', [
                '--path' => $migrationsPath,
                '--force' => true,
            ]);

            // When you reach this point
            // so all migrations have been successfully executed
            $connection->commit();
            $this->info('Migrations executed successfully.');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Restore data
            $restorationClosure();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: function runUp doesn't exists for migrator

Comment: and another problem that I haven't classes names for migrations

Comment: for info: https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.html#method_runUp

and tell me What version of Laravel are you currently working with?

Comment: 10, but as I checked error throws before -> in resolve method, like
Class "CreateTeamMembersTable" not found

I think it's because migrations starts as

return new class extends Migration

Comment: + runUp has paremeters
string $file int $batch bool $pretend

Comment: + it doesn't check existing migrations, too many problems even I fix previous

Comment: + isRun function doesn't exists too.

I know that code ChatGPT suggested, but I tried his suggestions and they don't work ;(

Comment: I created and tested the above code and it worked for me, you can try it, I am waiting for your feedback if you have any other issue 
(FYI, the above code allows you to rollback the latest migrations and also keep the data)

Comment: I don't think it will work, but I will try to use your features
If migration fails it doesn't add migration file to database but execute SQL before fail.
For example if you create 10 tables in one migration and it fails on 10, it will create 9 tables in database.

When you run your rollback command you remove previous migration, not this one.

That's why I want to implement rollback transactions on fail migration.

NOT laravel artisan migrate.

You code will broke database and rollback previous migration

Comment: It still says There is no active transaction
Artisan::call does independently and ignoring transactions
I think it works for you because you have one connection and one database.